# Replacing SBS 2008 DC with a Win 2008R2 DC

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs-2008

Objective : Replace a SBS 2008 with a Win 2008 R2 on or Domain and migrate Exchange 2010 to the new server.

Steps taken: The following steps were taken - [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2302c957-7db5-4c7c-8d40-81895bf9fc3a/small-business-server-2008-r2-transition-migration-to-server-standard-2008-r2) , [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/287436/recommended-way-to-replace-win-2003-sbs-server-with-win-2008-r2-server).

All the replication process completed well,DCHP and DNS are working well however im facing a wall :

1. the client users can't connect to shared folder and remote access ,the Win 2008r2 is unable to display  the various AD objects when the SBS 2008 is disconnected from the network .
2. The SBS 2008 is unable to be demoted ,the following error is displayed “No other Active Directory for this domain can be contacted"

We currently planning to rebuild the AD from scratch after exporting the users from the SBS 2008. but i'll like to know what can be the issue and if it can be successfully solved.

Comment: Are both servers using the correct DNS servers?

Comment: Yes ,since the Win 2008r2 was meant to replace the SBS we had the DNS pointing to himself. I also noticed that once i add the SBS Ip to the second NIC the AD seems to work for a while but then break down. At the DNS level all the reference to the SBS 2008 have been removed as well.
But the same issue was faced we currently meant to have the SBS connected to the network to have users working while trying to find a solution.